# Как сделать Progressbar в окне на холсте Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, progress-bar

Мне нужно показывать очки при каждом клике на кнопку. 
Как сделать `Progressbar` в окне на холсте `Canvas`?

```
canvas.pack()


clicks = 0



def click():
    global clicks
    
    clicks += 2
    canvas.delete("all")
    
    canvas.create_text(250, 10, text = clicks, font=('Arial Black', 10, 'bold'), fill = "#4587de")
    canvas.pack()
    

b1 = PhotoImage(file=здесь мой файл)
Button(root, image=b1, bd=0, command=click, height=100, width=100).place(x=220,y=85)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества меня окно tkinter, а я не знаю как нарисовать progressbar на canvas

Comment: Если быть более точнее, то я создаю игру кликер

Comment: "@Духсообщества"? Дух сообщества - бот

Comment: На canvas можно рисовать прямоугольник (create_rectangle), меняя его размер эмулировать прогрессбар. Также есть специальный контрол для Progressbar, его также можно на холсте разместить через create_window.

Comment: @insolor ну спасибо за подсказку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.i = 0
        
        self.canvas = Canvas()
        self.canvas.place(relx=0,rely=0)
        
        self.button = Button(self, text="Click me", command=self.animation)
        self.button.pack()

        self.label=Label(text="Вы еще не нажимали кнопкую")
        self.label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.85, anchor='c')

        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(orient='horizontal', mode="determinate", length=480)  
        self.pb.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9,anchor='c')        
        self.pb["value"] = 0
        
    def animation(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i > 100:
            self.label["text"] = f'Вы нажали кнопку 100 раз. Это все.'
            return
        
        self.pb["value"] = self.i
        self.label["text"] = f'Вы нажали кнопку {self.i} раз.'
        

root = Root()
root.geometry("500x400+500+200")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @МенОсы пожалуйста.